# Extracting MDCT coefficients for steganalysis?

Tags: mp3, steganography, coefficients

MP3Stego (http://www.petitcolas.net/steganography/mp3stego/) hides data within MP3 files during the inner_loop and uses part2_3_length to modify bits.

I'm wondering whether it would be worth extracting MDCT coefficients and examining them as a histogram to compare it with an MP3 file with no hidden data in it. However, from the encoding process of MP3s MDCT happens before the inner_loop.

Would there be any use of extracting the coefficients if this is the case? If so, would the best way of doing this just to print out data to file during the encoding process?

Comment: I didn't understand in what you are interested, mp3 steganography or just analysis of MDCT coefficents? Capacity of mp3stego was very limited, it was 2 bits per frame as I remember. If you just want the steganalysis of mp3stego, there were many articles related to that, like [this one](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5178971/).

Comment: @kdrtkl whether the analysis of the MDCT coefficients could be useful for steganalysis.

Comment: if the only goal is mp3stego program, then there are existing articles, as at the link in my previous comment, analyzing that program. Morever, mp3stego was opensource, so it may be helpful to have a look at the source code. Yet, if you are digging for a general steganalysis study, there are many more techniques have been tried in many transform domains, still all of these techniques are considered to be weak against machine learning tools.